# Isn't it better to not add a space after the colons in my css codes?

Tags: css

my question is perhaps a little silly.

I intentionally won't add any spaces after the colons in my css codes. The editing programs I use flag this as incorrect but the results are the same to me.

```
#burger {
width:60px;
opacity:0.5;
position:absolute;
cursor:pointer;
top:200px;
left:18%;
transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index:999;
user-select:none;
}
```

The reason I don't do it is that I believe (please correct me if I'm wrong) that all the extra spaces add upp and when you have big codes to read they can slow down the loading of the page.

Am I wrong? As I'm sure you can tell, I don't have a formal education when it comes to coding. So please forgive me if my question is stupid.

Appreciate clarity on the matter,
/Fred

Comment: If the minuscule size difference/data added to the file from using proper spacing for readability + other developers working on the project, you should probably have a minifier built into your deployment pipeline process somewhere along the way, or do so yourself. I would honestly recommend not worrying about it though unless it somehow ever becomes an issue. You'll run into size constraints and want to minify JS and CSS code because of other reasons long before any extra spacing is a concern.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion; it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

That makes your code readable, is better if you include the correct format, at the end when you deploy your code you can use a CSS Minifier to compress the size of your file, that's why exists min version in a lot of libraries.

that include your Javascript code as well.